# Как правильно и эффективно подключать заголовочный файл?

Tags: c++

Есть необходимость работать с **большой библиотекой** в нескольких файлах `.cpp` одного проекта. 
Возникает следующий вопрос: Если добавлять `#include <someBIGlib.h>` в оба `.cpp` файла, то не станет ли программа менее эффективной в плане производительности или веса из-за дублирующихся заголовков? 
 П. С.: Как я знаю, `#include` **вставляет содержимое** одного файла в другой, а при сборке проекта, все `.cpp` файлы преобразуются **в отдельные бинарники**, из чего я могу догадаться, что в каждом из них будет **продублирована** одна и та же информация, что является примером *плохой реализации*. 
Если я все правильно понял, то как это можно избежать?

Comment: «Большая библиотека» и «большой заголовочный файл» — это две очень сильно разные вещи, и включение заголовочного файла в общем случае не имеет никакого отношения к подключению библиотек (то есть статической или динамической линковке с ней), определитесь что конкретно у вас происходит

Comment: И то, и другое, так как без подключения заголовочного файла, предоставленного библиотекой, невозможно получить доступ к функционалу этой самой библиотеки.

Comment: Однако из этого совершенно не следует, что каждый отдельный бинарник будет содержать эту библиотеку, если выполняется динамическая линковка. Ещё раз внимательнее определитесь, что конкретно у вас происходит. А неиспользуемые определения заголовочного файла будут просто выброшены за ненадобностью

Comment: Хорошо, я исправил вопрос. Да, я понимаю, что каждый бинарник не будет содержать библиотеку, но, получается, если каждый файл будет использовать один и тот же метод, то его объявление (из заголовка) будет в каждом бинарнике?

Comment: ваш код не сможет увеличиваться от подключаемой библиотеки, так как она уже скомпилирована и у вас нет её исходников `.cpp`. Максимум вы можете просто вызывать её методы очень много раз.

Comment: Да, но подключать заголовочный файл в каждом `.cpp` кажется потребляет больше, чем потреблял бы тот же код в одном файле.